# Extracting JSON Keys from Two Dimensional Matrix

Tags: java, json, json-simple

When dealing with a valid JSON which represents a two dimensional matrix:

```
[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]
```

Using Java 1.8 and the json-simple lib:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Am able to obtain an individual row using the following?:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(args[0]);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
System.out.println(array.get(0));
```

This outputs:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

My question is how to extract the key values from this two dimensional matrix to output this:

```
'{ "a": [1,null,5], "b": [2,3,null], "c": [null,4,6] }'
```

Notice, that any variables that are missing from the row should have null inserted...

Answer (score 1):

General solution could look like below:

1. Read `JSON` payload as *ARRAY*.
2. Find all possible keys in all `JSON Object`'s in *ARRAY* and store them in *KEYS* set.
3. Iterate over all `JSON Object`'s in *ARRAY*.

   4. Iterate over all *KEYS* and get value or `null` from given `JSON Object`.

Using `Java 8` features we can implement it as below:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonSimpleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // input
        String json = "[ { \"a\":1, \"b\":2 }, { \"b\":3, \"c\":4 }, { \"c\":6, \"a\":5 } ]";

        // read as JSONArray
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(json);

        // Find all possible keys
        Set<String> keys = (Set<String>) array.stream().flatMap(i -> ((JSONObject) i).keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        // create result Map with KEY - LIST pair
        Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
        keys.forEach(key -> result.put(key, new ArrayList<>()));

        // Iterate over all JSONObject's
        array.forEach(item -> {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) item;
            // For each possible key add a value or NULL to each list
            keys.forEach(key -> result.get(key).add(object.remove(key)));
        });

        result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
a=[1, null, 5]
b=[2, 3, null]
c=[null, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces in json by key. For example:

```
obj["key"][0]
```

Then you can take the value

Comment: can you please show me how to do this via Java code?

Comment: Could you please delete this answer as it does not answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Simply you can use **JOLT** for this purpose.

> **JSON** to **JSON** transformation library written in Java where the
>   "specification" for the transform is itself a JSON document.

According to your scenario, you must Just:

1- Create a rule

2- Filter your input via this rule.

---

> - The **JSON input** is as follows

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "b": 3,
    "c": 4
  },
  {
    "c": 6,
    "a": 5
  }
]
```

> - The **filter** rule (JOLT spec) can be as follows

```
[
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {

       "*": {
         "a": "a",
         "b": "b",
         "c": "c"
       }

     }
   }
]
```

> - **result**

```
{
  "a" : [ 1, 5 ],
  "b" : [ 2, 3 ],
  "c" : [ 4, 6 ]
}
```

> **You can test the aforementioned solution in [here](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception)**

---

> - Java code for applying the aforementioned items in java

```
public class CustomJsonTransformer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Get filter (JOLT SPEC)
        List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.classpathToList("/filter.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);

        //Get input JSON
        Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToObject("/input.json");

        //Do filter
        Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

        //Result
        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
    }
}
```

> **1-  [This guide](https://www.hascode.com/2017/01/transforming-and-reducing-json-structures-with-jolt/) shows a pretty good sample on JOLT in java**
>
> **2-  Complete documentation of JOLT is [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#Documentation)**

Notice that, with the help of **JOLT** documentation, you can make the rule more complicated or easier (My rule was just a simple one)